# How to use matplotib.dates.date2num to get widths of bars in bar plot?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, matplotlib, width, histogram

I am trying to make a bar plot for which the x-axis is scaled by datetimes. I can create the plot, but I am not sure how to verify the accuracy of the graph because I do not entirely understand how `date2num` via `matplotlib.dates` works. [According to the docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num), it returns the following:

> > Number of days (fraction part represents hours, minutes, seconds, ms) since 0001-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, plus one.

So, should a change in graph be noticed if the x-axis ticks (minor or major) are formatted to show months (or days or years) when using `date2num`? I have a little demo below that may help make more sense of this.

In the example below, I need `date2num` to calculate the width of each bar; otherwise, I need to specify the unit using a `datetime.timedelta` object. In my actual use case, the datetimes correspond to clusters of events; I would like to show the y-values as the number of events in a cluster, for which the width of the bar extends along x from the datetimes of the first and last events in said cluster.

Consider the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import date2num, YearLocator, MonthLocator, DayLocator, WeekdayLocator, HourLocator, MinuteLocator, SecondLocator, DateFormatter

lbound = datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 25, 0, 0, 0)
dts = []
for i in range(10):
    new_dt = lbound + i * datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    dts.append(new_dt)
edges = np.array(dts)

# print("\n .. {} EDGES:\n{}\n".format(edges.size, edges))

 .. 10 EDGES:
[datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 25, 0, 0)
 datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 26, 0, 0)
 datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 27, 0, 0)
 datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 28, 0, 0)
 datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 29, 0, 0)
 datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 30, 0, 0)
 datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 31, 0, 0) datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0)
 datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 2, 0, 0) datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 3, 0, 0)]
```

Given `10` datetimes, suppose I take the midpoint of every two consecutive datetimes to be the x-coordinate, and the width of each bar to be the time in-between these consecutive datetimes. (The y-coordinate (height of bar) is arbitrary in this example.) This can be done using `date2num` via `matplotlib.dates`:

```
xs, ws = [], []
for lower_edge, upper_edge in zip(edges[1:], edges[:-1]):
    _lw = date2num(lower_edge)
    _uw = date2num(upper_edge)
    w = _uw - _lw
    xs.append(_lw + w/2)
    ws.append(w)

xs = np.array(xs)
ws = np.array(ws)
ys = np.sin(xs)
```

The plot can be obtained by:

```
fmt = "%Y-%m-%d"
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(xs, ys, width=ws, color='r')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter(fmt))
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=15)
plt.show()
plt.close(fig)
```

[image: Example output plot]

In case it is unclear, I am asking if `date2num` is the appropriate way to get the bar widths for *any* x-axis formatting. If not, what is a better way?

Comment: It is the appropriate way for any x axis that shows datetimes, yes.

Comment: If I may ask a "why/how" follow-up, I could compute the differences manually as `datetime.timedelta(**kwargs)`, where `kwargs` could be something like `dict(hours=3)` or `dict(days=5)`. How does `date2num` know which unit to calculate the differences?

Comment: Matplotlib's numeric datetime format is always days.